# Use of URLs in CSS vars with Edge Browser

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

Example: https://github.com/rikrak/EdgeUrlVar

We're trying to improve our use of CSS by implementing vars.  We've hit a problem whereby Chrome and Firefox work fine, but Edge (and IE11) appear to interpret the paths in the CSS relative to the page, rather than the css file.
I can't find a way to work around this without resorting to absolute paths, which I'd rather avoid.

**Structure:**

```
+-Accounts
|    +-index.html
+-Resources
|    +-ClientOne
|    |    +-css
|    |    |    +-client.css
|    |    +-images
|    |         +-logo.png
|    +-Shared
|         +-css
|              +-common.css
+index.html
```

**client.css:**

```
:root{
    --logo:url('../../../Resources/ClientOne/Images/logo.png');
}
```

**common.css**

```
.title{
    background-image: var(--logo);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 80px;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo of CSS vars</title>
        <link href="Resources/Shared/Css/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="Resources/ClientOne/Css/client.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="title"></div>
        <h2>Home Page</h2>
        <p>Go to <a href="Accounts/index.html">Accounts</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Accounts/index.html** (both are similar)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo of CSS vars</title>
        <link href="../Resources/Shared/Css/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="../Resources/ClientOne/Css/client.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="title"></div>
        <h2>Accounts Page</h2>
        <p>Go <a href="../index.html">Home</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: IE does not support CSS Variables, and only Edge 16+ supports them.

Comment: Ta.  I'm using Edge v44.17763.771.0 in this case

Comment: I believe this is a known issue with EdgeHTML. I don't know if I'm misremembering though.

Comment: As @Yu Zhou points out, the example above does not illustrate the point when hosted.  I've updated the linked github repo to have more folder depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just browse the page through local file path, then the logo can't show in IE and Edge. But if you publish it as a website, it can work well in Edge and Chrome.

Besides, IE doesn't support CSS variables, you could [add a polyfill](https://github.com/nuxodin/ie11CustomProperties) to make it work in IE. You just need to import **ie11CustomProperties.js** into the page where you use the CSS variables. In this case, we can add the JavaScript file to **index.html** and **Accounts/index.html**.

I add the polyfill and [publish the website to IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPsh1.png) and it can work well in all browsers: [result in IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK999.gif), [result in Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbZR1.gif).

-------------------------------------------------------------Edit------------------------------------------------------------------

You could use root-relative path with "/" to avoid the issue. Please try to change **client.css** into this:

```
:root{
    --logo:url('/Resources/ClientOne/Images/logo.png');
}
```

Comment: Blimey, you're right.  I think when I set this up I was using a virtual folder under the default website of IIS.  I've added extra levels to the GitHub project to better illustrate the point.  For me it begins to fail at a folder depth of 4

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with more folder depth. It finds out the wrong path of logo image from folder depth of 4. It can be solved by using root-relative path. You could check my updated answer.

Comment: This is how I ended up resolving it.